# Java inheritance, changing parameter type in base class

Tags: java, inheritance

Suppose we have some `Base` class with a method with `Object` parameter, and in a newer vesion developers decide to change `Ojbect` to `int`.

for example:

```
public class Base {
   public void foo(Object i)
     {
           System.out.println("ahahaa");
     }
}

public class Child extends Base
{
    public void foo(Object i)
   {
       System.out.println("tru-la-la");
   }
}
```

Then new version of Base:

```
public class Base
{
     public void foo(int i)
     {
           Console.WriteLine("ahahaa");
     }
}
```

Then if we call something like:

```
Child child = new Child();
child.foo(5);
```

We'll get "ahaha" instead of expected "tru-la-la"

So how can we deal with it, and what architecture solution should we use?

Comment: Why did you expect `tru-la-la`?

Comment: Why you expect "tru-la-la"? 5 ins an int and so the method with type `int` is called

Comment: See Java Language Spec: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5

Comment: we have instance of child class and there we have method which accepts Object which is wider then int, so it suppose to call parent's method with int params, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are not looking for an explanation regarding why you get "ahaha" and not "tru-la-la" (which you used to get before the change in the Base class).

If you are releasing libraries to be used by other developers, you are expected to maintain backward comptibility. The chnage you describe in the Base class clearly doesn't respect backward comptibility, so any code that relies on it would break.

There's nothing you can do other than change your code or stop using that library.

You can change your code, for example, by calling `child.foo(new Integer(5))`, which would invoke the sub-class method.

Another thing that can help is to mark the method in the Child class with `@Override` annotation. This would stop your code from compiling after the change in the Base class.

Comment: ok, thanks, sure it's not real life example, c# programmers asked about this feature in java, because in c# it wiil be called child method anyway

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an int -child.foo(5); then the JVM will naturaly take the method in the child object that is most specific. In this case it is 
a choice between

public void foo (Object i) {

&

public void foo (int i) {

the more specific is --

public void foo(int i) {
which writes "ahahaa"